# JAR inclusion not working

Tags: java, jar, rmi

I am learning how to create an RMI system, and I compiled the shared classes into a .jar, but when I try to include it, the following error occurs:

```
javac -cp compute.jar Client.java

Client.java:6: error: package rmi.interfaces does not exist
import rmi.interfaces.Tasks;
                     ^
Client.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                        Tasks stub = (Tasks) registry.lookup("Tasks");
                        ^
  symbol:   class Tasks
  location: class Client
Client.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                        Tasks stub = (Tasks) registry.lookup("Tasks");
                                      ^
  symbol:   class Tasks
  location: class Client
3 errors
```

The classes it needs are inside the jar, but for some reason it can't find them. How can I fix this?

Comment: It would probably be useful to use an actual IDE to compile your program. The 3 most popular are [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) and [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/)

Comment: Yup, most likely. I tried doing it the Oracle way but as always, it's not working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message says that `rmi.interfaces` package is not on your classpath. In you example this means not in `compute.jar`. You could verify that by typing `zipinfo -1 compute.jar` to see what entries are inside the JAR.

You really should setup a build tool for your project. You really shouldn't be compiling Java by hand unless you are learning what is `javac`. If you want to try Maven you can clone [rm5248/Java-RMI-Example](https://github.com/rm5248/Java-RMI-Example) to see how to set up an RMI project with independent client and server modules.